# Using postfix for private network

Tags: linux, email, smtp, postfix-mta, mutt

We have a custom based hardware running Linux. It generates a daily report by a script which is executed by cron.

Our requirement is to have all the devices on the private network send an email with this daily report (.txt) file as an attachment.

I have installed postfix as a SMTP Server on one of the machine. I am not getting any idea of how I can proceed to the next step which I believe is creating accounts ( emailid/password ) and I have email client ( mutt ) installed on the other devices.

How can I proceed or what are the steps required to achieve my requirement

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more steps you need to take in order to get your Postfix installation working the way you want. Several guides are available for this depending on what you want the email server to do. The hosting service Digita Ocean has some nice setup guides for starters. 
Try googling "postfix digitalocean".